# Fortran Allocate array with size to be read from file

Tags: arrays, fortran, dimension, intel-fortran

I am reading from a file that contains a value, T, which will be used to initialize several arrays that will take T as the first dimension with allocate later. i.e.

```
subroutine read_file(T,F,array,A,B,C,...)
    ...
    real, intent(out) :: T,F
    real, intent(in) :: A,B,C
    real, intent(out) :: array
    ...
    read(1,*) T
    ...
    read(1,*) F
    ...
    read(1,*) array(1), array(5), array(6)
    read(1,*) array(2), array(4)
    read(1,*) array(3)
    ...
    if (F.eq.1) then
        array(1) = A(1)
        array(2) = B(2)
        array(3) = C(3)
    endif
    ...
program main
    ...
    do I=1,nproc
        ...
        do J=1,nsteps
            ...
            call read_file(T,F,array,A,B,C,...)
            ...
        enddo
        ...
        if (F.eq.1.and.etc.) then
            ...
            allocate(A(T,3))
            allocate(B(T,6))
            allocate(C(T))
            ...
        endif
        ...
    enddo
```

The read statement is contained in a read_file subroutine in a module in modules.for. The allocate statements are in main.for where read_file is also called.

Subroutine read_file also reads many other things and it is called many times over the course of 1 execution of the code where some files may have T be zero.

I need to pass in A, B, and C into read_file. Depending on the condition of a flag, F, also being read in read_file, the values in A, B, and C need to be assigned to array(1,6) that would otherwise be read directly from the file.

So I guess my question is: How do I pass in arrays that may not have been allocated in size? I have written checks in the code to make sure A, B, and C will not be actually used unless they went through allocation with a known size given as user input T, but the compiler has been giving me issues.

I tried compile the code and intel compiler first returned the error saying the types for A,B,C are not declared in read_file, so I declared them using T and `real :: A(T,3)` in read_file. Then it said since T is a `intent(out)`, it cannot be used to give dimension to A, B, and C since they are `intent(in)`. So I removed the `intent(out)` from T (as in it is just `real :: T` now).

And now, the error says:

> If the actual argument is scalar, the dummy argument shall be scalar
>   unless the actual argument is of type character or is an element of an
>   array that is not assumed shape, pointer, or polymorphic.

I edited my question to provide more code and clarify my question.

Thanks to the people who answered and commented, I now know that I can declare a variable as allocatable in the subroutine, which should solve my problem.

Thanks!

Jesse

Comment: Omg, I am having a bad time trying to understand your question. Could you pls be more clear and also put in some minimal code? (see [mcve] and [ask])

Comment: Fixed-form has nothing to do with your problem.  You can actually allocate `A`, `B`, and `C` in your subroutine.  Change the interface to `real, intent(out), allocatable :: a(:,:), b(:,:), c(:)`, then in your subroutine after reading `T` allocate the variables.  You get the possible side benefit that `intent(out)` will automatically deallocate `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Comment: "_so I declared them using T and `real :: A(T,3)`_". Where did you declare them? Are you writing a procedure inside _read_file_ that receives the arrays A, B, C as arguments? If so, instead of passing them as explicit-shape (`A(T,3)`), can't you just pass them as assumed-shape (`A(:,:)`)?

Comment: @evets I see, I can definitely use allocatable then I can allocate it when the flag is on.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Yes I declared real :: A(T,3) inside the subroutine at the time because I didn't know what else to do. So I can pass them in as assumed-shape? That would be great

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I have edited my question. Hopefully, it is clearer now but my question has been answered. Thanks!

Comment: If my edit doesn't get accepted, please remove "fixed form" from the title here. This was the first result when I searched for "fixed form intent(out)" on Google, and unfortunately the question has nothing to do with fixed-form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the safest way to deal with the problem you describe is to let read_file handle the allocation, that is, pass `A,B,C` to read_file as

```
real, intent(inout), allocatable :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
```

With `intent(inout)` allowing you to call read_file multiple times with the same `A,B,C` without losing the information from previous calls. If that is not required, feel free to use just `intent(out)`. Passing unallocated arrays as arguments is fine, just make sure to have the allocation happen before any access is attempted.

You can then allocate `A,B,C` inside read_file, after `T` has been read in.

If tempering with read_file is not possible, or you want to have the allocation to happen in main, you can also use the approach you described. First, allocate A,B,C as dummy arrays

```
allocate(A(0,0), B(0,0), C(0,0))
```

which you can pass to the first call of read_file (0-sized arrays are allowed, just make sure you do not try to access their entries). If I understood correctly, the first call will not perform any operations on `A,B,C` and they are only required to be allocated in subsequent calls to read_file. If that is the case, allocating in main.for also works.

Once you obtained T, you can reallocate A,B,C with

```
if(allocated(A)) deallocate(A)
allocate(A(T,3))
```

You can then pass the reallocated arrays to the next call of read_file.

Comment: So to summarize, I can do the following: 1. pre-allocate as 0,0 dimension arrays, just make sure they are not used unless actually allocated. 2. declare A,B,C as allocatable and allocate them inside read_file, but needs to deallocate if it has been allocated. 3. declare them as assumed-shape.

Comment: One question: if I deallocate, I assume it erases the contents. What happens if I don't deallocate and allocate it again?

Comment: Sorry, one more question: would `intent(inout), allocatable` erase the contents of A, B, and C if they come in with values and already properly allocated?

Comment: Corret, if you deallocate, the content is erased. If you attempt to allocate an already allocated array, an error will be thrown, so make sure you deallocate first.

Comment: When passing as `intent(inout), allocatable`, the content will not be erased and allocation is not changed upon calling read_file

Comment: Nice to see a NECI programmer here @KaiGuther!